# SQL query crashing PHPMYADMIN - issue with query logic

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some data consistency problems that occurred as a result of one bug.

Now I am trying to sort it out but somehow when I run part of my test query `phpmyadmin` crashes or becomes unresponsive for a very long time.
 i tried running the nested subqueries on their own and they work fine.

Basically the questions I am trying to solve are:

How do I delete the duplicate `resource_type=1` FROM `geo_address` FROM all users that have more than one `resource_type=1`  WHERE that user also has a `geo_address` with `resource_type=2`

Basically it means that if the user has a 2 `resource_type=1` and 1 `resource_type=2` he has a duplicate `resource_type=1`. If the user has 2 `resource_type=1` but no `resource_type=2` then it would fall into a different condition that I am not addressing here.

I am finding great trouble around the logic of my `SQL` query

What I have so far came up with is this but I know its fundamentaly wrong as it crashes

How could I build my query properly?

```
SELECT member_num
  FROM geo_address2 
 WHERE     id IN (SELECT id 
                    FROM geo_address2 
                   WHERE resource_type=1 
                GROUP BY member_num 
                  HAVING COUNT(resource_type) > 1
        )
       AND id IN (SELECT id 
                    FROM geo_address2 
                   WHERE resource_type=2 
                GROUP BY member_num 
                  HAVING COUNT(resource_type) = 1 
        )
```

Comment: can u give an example with data in sqlfiddle?

Comment: Where a user has "duplicate" records, which is the one that you want to keep?

Comment: @eggyal I want to keep the `MIN(id)` record with `resource_type=1` if there is a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion, I edited the answer.
One option is to use this query:

```
DELETE 
  FROM geo_address2
 WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT g12.id
                FROM (SELECT member_num, 
                             id
                        FROM geo_address2 
                       WHERE resource_type = 1) g1
              JOIN 
                     (SELECT member_num, 
                             id
                        FROM geo_address2 
                       WHERE resource_type = 1) g12
                   ON g1.member = g12.member AND g1.id > g12.id
                     (SELECT member_num, 
                             id
                        FROM geo_address2 
                       WHERE resource_type = 2) g2
                   ON g1.member_num = g2.member_num
               );
```

The second (I believe it is logically the same):

```
DELETE 
  FROM geo_address2
 WHERE id IN (
            SELECT g1.id
              FROM geo_address2 g0
                   JOIN geo_address2 g1
                        ON (g0.member_num = g1.member_num 
                            AND g0.id > g1.id
                            AND g0.resource_type = 1
                            AND g1.resource_type = 1)
                   JOIN geo_address2 g2
                        ON (g1.member_num = g2.member_num
                            AND g0.resource_type = 1
                            AND g2.resource_type = 2)
               );
```

Comment: what are you counting with cnt? is not defined

Comment: @JonathanThurft edited alias in `SELECT`, but forgot to change in `HAVING`. fixed

Comment: I want to keep the `MIN(id)` with  `resource_type = 1` if there is a duplicate and delete the others `resource_type = 1`

Comment: Added another query (slightly less symbols and less subqueries)

Comment: Ye, I reckon those should do it.  Mine would be more sargable, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE dupe
FROM   geo_address2 dupe
  JOIN geo_address2 keep
    ON dupe.id > keep.id
   AND dupe.member_num = keep.member_num
   AND dupe.resource_type = keep.resource_type
  JOIN geo_address2 save
    ON save.member_num = dupe.member_num
   AND save.resource_type = 2
WHERE  dupe.resource_type = 1
```